# Azure B2C SSO to protect Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, azure-application-gateway

Similar to Kubernetes Architectures that implement Authentication Proxy Layers for OAuth2.0, how can I implement Single-Sign-On with Azure B2C to protect all in-coming requests to Azure Application Gateway, that is protecting multiple backend Azure App Services that are routed with path prefixes (e.g. "/orders", "/warranty", etc.)

We would also like to get the current user's authentication information (e.g. Azure B2C Object ID, user attributes, etc.) in the downstream request to Azure App Service so we can implement Authorization in the App Service.

We tried to create Azure Application Gateway with tier "Web Application Firewall" and managed rule sets, but cannot find a single place to configure Single-Sign-On at the Application Gateway level.

Comment: you can configure Azure AD B2C as an identity provider for your Application Gateway. Once configured, all incoming requests will be redirected to the Azure AD B2C sign-in page, where users can authenticate themselves. After successful authentication, the user will be redirected back to the Application Gateway, which will then forward the request to the appropriate backend Azure App Service.

Comment: To get the current user's authentication information in the downstream request to Azure App Service, you can use the Azure AD B2C policy parameter. With the policy parameter, you can use OAuth 2.0 to add policies to your app, such as sign-up, sign-in, and profile management user flows. You can then use the user flow to get the user's authentication information and pass it along to the downstream Azure App Service. It's worth noting that Azure Application Gateway does not have a built-in SSO feature. Instead, you will need to configure SSO using Azure AD B2C as described above.

Comment: @Arko Are you sure Azure Application Gateway offers this? "Azure AD B2C as an identity provider for your Application Gateway". Yes, Azure API Management service offers some out-of-box identity provider integrations. But Azure Application Gateway (as of March 26, 2024) doesn't support this, or is not clear how to configure it and no clear documentation (official or unofficial)

We feel that using APIM to protect App Services is a risk as APIM is ideally designed for APIs, not Web Apps. Our Web Apps could break if the Azure product team change any behaviours for APIM unexpectedly.

Comment: Hmm. they stopped it huh? And you don't want to go with the APIM approach..